# CSS display inline block How can I prevent rearrangement?

Tags: html, css

I have a small question. Normally I would be ok with the divs rearranging on the screen if the screen is smaller, but for this particular case- I want them to remain the way they are no matter.

I think its the **inline-block** that may be causing this, but I need all the 4 color rectangles to display the way they display on large screen--throughout (the colorful blocks are 2x2 and the big ones are side by side as well).

When the screen is scaled, it places all on top of one another. I actually do not want this effect--how can this be avoided?

```css
#tools{

background-color: #EEAD0E;
cursor:pointer;

}
#corner{



background-color: #009ACD;
cursor:pointer;
}
#expert{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#BDD09F;
}

.floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 380px;
    height: 105px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

#pres{

background-color: #00FF00;
cursor: pointer;
}
#discussions{

background-color: green;
cursor: pointer;
}


.floating-box2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 305px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-box2"></div>
<div class="floating-box2"></div>


<div id="expert"  class="floating-box">
<img src="image.png"/></div>
<div id="tools" class="floating-box"><img src="image2.png"/></div><br>
<div id="discussions" class="floating-box"><img src="image3.png"/></div>
<div id="corner" class="floating-box"><img src="image4.png"/></div>
```

Comment: You have a fixed width to `380px` so if screen goes below `760px` it is natural that these elements will stack.

Comment: If you want this a bit responsive, check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/b5nyr02s/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you have a fixed with like you have `width:380px` it's obvious they won't fit together. you need to set a percentage width.

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t70u1290/1/)**

if you add text , add `vertical-align:top` to the floating boxes. this is because `display:inline-block` automatically implies `vertical-align:baseline`

code:

```
#tools{
    background-color: #EEAD0E;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#corner{
    background-color: #009ACD;
    cursor:pointer;
} 
#expert{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#BDD09F;
}
.floating-box {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 105px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#pres{

    background-color: #00FF00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#discussions{

    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.floating-box2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 305px;
    border: 3px solid #d3d3d3;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: why does inserting text push the divs down in the top two blocks?

Comment: add `vertical-align:top` to the floating boxes. `display:inline-block` by default aligns items to baseline ; *edited my answer *